# How to make an atrous convolutional neural network diagram?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, object-detection

I am working on a fire detection project and I use the atrous cnn model as below:

```
model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', dilation_rate=2, input_shape=(224, 224, 3)),
    BatchNormalization(),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', dilation_rate=2),
    BatchNormalization(),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
    Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(0.5),
    Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
```

with the model summary as below:
[image]

I am not sure how to create a diagram. Can you tell me whether I make it correctly? If not, please tell me how to make a change to it.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You created the diagram correctly. Because you are using a `dilation_rate==2`, both on the X and Y there is one empty space, so your dilation rate is correct. Remember that when `dilation==1` you get the regular/normal convolution.